# How to make dynamic pages seo friendly url using htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, seo, url-rewriting

In my php page i have given link as  href="test.php?category="xyz".
In url I want this page link to appear as "test/xyz".

In my .htaccess file i have added

```
RewriteRule ^test/([a-zA-Z]+) test.php?category=$
```

but this does'nt work for me.

All the other links in test.php gets test appended to their links.
eg. if there was example.php its appears as test/example.php

Help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: post your full .htaccess code.

Comment: This is my .htaccess file
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on           
    RewriteBase /mysite  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php    
    
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteRule ^test/([a-zA-Z]+) test.php?category=$1 

    ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mysite.com/page_not_found.php
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code can help you

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/([a-zA-Z]+)$ test.php?category=$1
</IfModule>
```

Try to access these urls : `test.php?category=abc` and `test/abc`. If two pages show the same content this code successful.
To learn more, please read the [**reference here**](http://tutorial.world.edu/web-development/create-seo-friendly-urls-rewrite-htaccess-mod_rewrite/)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like you forgot the use full relative paths in your links. Instead of using:

```
<a href="example.php">example</a>
```

You should use:

```
<a href="/example.php">example</a>
```

Else when you are on page `/test/abcd`, going to `example.php` means `/test/example.php`

Comment: I have given full link in php page in a tag as                       <a href="www.mysite.com/test.php?category=xyz">Example</a>

Comment: That good, but what are all other links? (i.e. the example.php in the last lines of your question)

Comment: After coming in test.php all links in this file gets "test" appended infront of the file. eg. If in test.php there is enquiry.php file it goes to test/enquiry.php