# htaccess URL Redirect for sub directory?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i am working on a sub directory for my site

```
www.example.com/me/index.php
```

and another page on which i am working is

```
www.example.com/me/showme.php?post=i-am-from-india
```

this will show me the complete post but i want it to be like this

```
www.example.com/me/showme/i-am-from-india
```

i have found and reference over [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623982) but it is not working in my case.

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `/.htaccess` have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /me/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^me(/.*)?$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /me/showme.php?post=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Those type of comments never help since it tells nothing about the error/problem. Is `/me/showme/i-am-from-india` causing 404? Did you create a new `/me/.htaccess` or used an existing one? Are there more rules in this file? If yes then post them in question.

Comment: There were many more questions in my comment. Apart from that also tell me what URL gave you 404?

Comment: i have created new .htaccess to sub directory and copied the code provided by you. then i visited my site and tried to access url that i have required and  shows me error 404

Comment: Do you have some PHP/CMS framework running in `/blog/` sub directory?

Comment: i have one more query in this. i want to remove all the sub directory links from there. i want just domain.com/title. is it possible

Comment: So instead of `/me/some-title` you want `/some-title`?

Comment: ok see updated, and this goes in root `.htaccess`. Though I suggest that it is not a good practice to change question via comments. Always better to close existing existing question and create a new one.